# What parameters are supported by install4j generated installers?

Tags: install4j

What parameters are supported by install4j generated installers? I've been tasked with deploying an app that is installed by a install4j-based install executable, however none of the standard MSI parameters apply?

Regards
Jason

Answer (score 0):

The available parameters are listed in the documentation:

https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/options.html